# Regex Expression in single SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

If an input string is in the format **String#String** or **String#String;String#String** where String can have any number of Capital letter alphabets, underscore,then it should return **Y** else it should return **N**.

How can it be done using Regex in PL/SQL only in single SQL query?
(P.S. not using PL/SQL procedures/function.)

Example:- If input string is **"CASISA#Y"** or **"INVOPT#LUMREG;LUMSUM#2000;REGSUM#8000"**, a 'Y' should be returned else an 'N' should be returned.
Note - Please do not build a PL/SQL procedure to accomplish this instead it should be just a SQL that makes use of oracle Regular expression functions.***

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little bit?  Provide an example string and indicate the substrings you are trying to match.  What have you tried already?

Comment: plsql check question again i have added example

Comment: What is the version of Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_like` regular expression function to achieve desired result:

```
with t1(col) as(
  select 'CASISA#Y'                              from dual union all
  select 'INVOPT#LUMREG;LUMSUM#2000;REGSUM#8000' from dual union all
  select 'CASISA#Y;'                             from dual union all -- extra data
  select 'INVOPT#LUMREG;LUMSUM#2000;#8000'       from dual           -- extra data
)
select col
     , case
         when regexp_like(col, '^(\w+#\w+;)*(\w+#\w+){1}$')
         then 'Y'
         else 'N'
       end  as "Y/N"
  from t1
```

Result:

```
COL                                        Y/N
--------------------------------------------------
CASISA#Y                                    Y
INVOPT#LUMREG;LUMSUM#2000;REGSUM#8000       Y
CASISA#Y;                                   N
INVOPT#LUMREG;LUMSUM#2000;#8000             N
```

[**SQLFiddle example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/6300)